# Haskell-ish way to define values for enums

Tags: haskell, enums

I'm looking for a Haskell-ish way to define values for enums. Here is what I currently have:

```
data Binop
   = Plus
   | Minus
   | Times
   | Divide
   -- deriving ( Show ) <--- removed this

instance Show Binop where
    show Plus   = "+"
    show Minus  = "-"
    show Times  = "*"
    show Divide = "/"
```

It would be nice to have the constant values (`"+"`, `"-"` etc.) in the `Binop` data type.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for *annotations*: https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/annotations

Comment: You can rename them `data Binop = (:+) | (:-) | (:*) | (:/) deriving Show` but that makes more sense if they are actual operators. I assume you want to use `Binop` as an argument to some `Binary Binop Exp Exp`..

Comment: @Iceland_jack yes, it's for bundling a left and right expressions.

Comment: What is the usecase?

Comment: usecase = dump AST to graphviz. I prefer "+" over "Plus"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you wrote seems fine, modulo the usual complaint about a strong convention: the `Show` instance should produce valid Haskell code that reproduces the value. I might consider returning a `Char` instead of a `String` unless you're sure that `String` is better, so something like:

```
name :: Binop -> Char
name = \case
    Plus -> '+'
    Minus -> '-'
    Times -> '*'
    Divide -> '/'
```

If there's a lot of them, you could consider making a lookup table for compactness, though I'm not at all confident that this will be more efficient.

```
name :: Binop -> Char
name = (listArray (minBound, maxBound) "+-*/" !)
```

I guess you'd need to define an `Ix` instance as well, but you can reuse the `Ix Int` and `Enum Binop` instances to make that pretty short; or use the same basic idea but backed by a `Map` instead of an `Array`.

Comment: I'm curious about the `\case` expression - where is it defined? Is it some language extension? (I was only aware of the `case ... of ...` expressions.)

Comment: @flawr Yes, it is the `LambdaCase` extension.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what "valid Haskell code that produces the value" means ?

Comment: @OrenIshShalom The derived instance, for example. `show Plus = "Plus"` produces a string that contains valid Haskell code, and if you run that code, you get back the value you started with.

Comment: so if I understand you correctly, it is "not-haskellish" to assign string values to enums at all ? because if I want the "default" show, I might as well derive from it, right ?

Comment: @OrenIshShalom It is perfectly Haskellish. Just don't call the function that does that assignment `show` unless it roundtrips with `read` and with spawning ghci.

Answer (score 0):

`(+)`, `(-)` etc are not "values" that you want since they are functions, and you can't compare equality between functions like you would do with "normal values". Of course, you can create a function that translates the `Binop` to the corresponding binary operator function, and this could come handy when you implement evaluation-related functions.

However, Haskell Enums do come with intrinsic indices:

```
fromEnum :: Enum a => a -> Int
```

In this way, you can have `fromEnum Plus = 0`, `fromEnum Minus = 1`, and so on. All you need to do is `deriving Enum` immediately after defining the data `Binop`.

Comment: I don't think the OP wants the *functions* in the definition of `Binop`, just the symbols.

Comment: If just simple String symbols, then the "show" approach right now is OK

Comment: yes, I meant `"+"`, `"-"` ... sorry too many quoting symbols - I'll fix my question